# Android Studio - Colors cannot be found

Tags: android, android-studio

details:

> error: style attribute 'attr/colorTextGreen (aka
>   com.example.a92317.ltka:attr/colorTextGreen)' not found.
>   Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: style attribute 'attr/colorTextGreen
>   (aka com.example.a92317.ltka:attr/colorTextGreen)' not found.,
>   sources=[C:\Users\92317.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.0.2.aar\42626cc3773e81f375f5215b1d4a6d01\res\values\values.xml:391:5-397:13],
>   original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}

colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
<color name="colorTextGreen">#006600</color>
<color name="colorBackgroundGreen">#F0F8FF</color>
<color name="colorTransparent">#00000000</color>
</resources>
```

styles.xml:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
<item name="colorTextGreen">@color/colorTextGreen</item>
<item name="colorBackgroundGreen">@color/colorBackgroundGreen</item>
<item name="colorTransparent">@color/colorTransparent</item>
</style>
<style name="FontStyle" parent="AppTheme">
<item name="android:fontFamily">@font/newfont</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

How could I do to solve it?
I'm dying...

Comment: Shouldn't be reflected with that error, but resources is missing the top xml tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

following is not a valid item name

```
<item name="colorTextGreen">@color/colorTextGreen</item>
```

**you can only use item names that specify an attribute in your xml layout. The value in the  element is the value for that attribute.**

example

```
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorTextGreen</item>
```

this will be default background color because we set the item name to color for theme.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create `item`s with you own name, in this case you created a `colorTextGreen` and a `colorBackgroundGreen`, this is no possible. The `item` has predefined name, so, you must just use it passing a value.